# Drupal - How to get watchdog messages and display them on the page?

Tags: php, drupal-7, content-management-system

How to get watchdog messages and display them on the page?

This would be useful for debugging.

Comment: Which drupal version ? Do you need to tail messages or should the page remain static ?

Comment: I use drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your code, and when `watchdog()` called message will be saved in messages section in admin panel with "debug" type.

See also https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/watchdog/7.x

```
<?php
 watchdog('debug', 'Something went wrong');
?>
```

Comment: What I want is actually to display in my theme programmatically.

Comment: If you want to display message once it has arisen, than you may use drupal_set_message() function. If you want to print all log or some part of it to the page than you may create custom database request to watchdog table.

Comment: Also this module may be useful [Views Watchdog](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_watchdog)